# Java Hibernate OneToOne Exception Mapping Error?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have the follow classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "seek")
public class Seek implements  Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="url")
    private Url url;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "url")
public class Url implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idSeek", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Seek seek;

}
```

My Url table has the idSeek column, my Seek table doesn't have any relationship column  with url table.

The exception that I receive is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'seekDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory dao.hibernate.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [configuration/HibernateConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne: model.Url.url in mappedBy of model.Seek.url
```

My DAOs just extend

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {

private final Class<T> persistentClass;

public AbstractDao() {
    this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
}

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

protected Session getSession() {
    return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

public T getByKey(PK key) {
    return (T) this.getSession().get(this.persistentClass, key);
}

public T getByColumn(String column, String value) {
    Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(this.persistentClass);
    return (T) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(column, value)).uniqueResult();
}

public void persist(T entity) {
    this.getSession().persist(entity);
}

public void delete(T entity) {
    this.getSession().delete(entity);
}

protected Criteria createEntityCriteria() {
    return this.getSession().createCriteria(this.persistentClass);
}

protected Query getQuery(String query) {
    return this.getSession().createQuery(query);
}
```

}

like that

```
@Repository("seekDao")
public class SeekDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, Seek> implements SeekDao {

    @Override
    public Seek get(int id) {
        return super.getByKey(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Seek seek) {
        super.persist(seek);
    }
}
```

I don't know much about Hibernate, where is the problem?

**EDITED**

I did It, and now compiles but now I receive this: WARN:   SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
ERROR:   Column 'idSeek' cannot be null

My method at service class is:

```
// my service is @Transactional
@Override
public void saveSeek(Seek seek)
{
    this.seekDao.save(seek);

    this.urldao.save(seek.getUrl());//the url is inside the seek obj
}
```

So I need to get the insert id manually and put at my url obj?
thanks

Comment: i think you need to change to `@OneToOne(mappedBy="seek")` at your Seek class for the url property.

Comment: Maybe `mappedBy="seek"`?

Comment: I receive the: WARN: SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000 ERROR: Column 'idSeek' cannot be null, when I try to save my models... My question was modified, after the word EDITED ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Seek class is not pointing to correct `mappedBy` property.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "seek")
public class Seek implements  Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="seek")
    private Url url;

}
```

Comment: thanks, I did that, but now I have other doubt... Can you help?

Comment: I receive the: WARN: SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000 ERROR: Column 'idSeek' cannot be null, when I try to save my models... My question was modified, after the word EDITED ...

Comment: since you are using a bidirectional relationship, you must update both entities with their foreign references. please have a look here. http://uaihebert.com/jpa-mini-book-first-steps-and-detailed-concepts/19/

Answer (score 0):

Try  changing `@OneToOne(mappedBy="url")` to `@OneToOne(mappedBy="seek")`

Comment: Can you please provide a little more explanation. What impact your change would have on the problem may be?

Comment: The mappedBy attribute is only necessary for a bidirectional relationship, this element can be omitted on the annotation...

Comment: thanks, I did that, but now I have other doubt... Can you help?

Comment: I receive the: WARN: SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000 ERROR: Column 'idSeek' cannot be null, when I try to save my models... My question was modified, after the word EDITED ...